# MKR1000 disconnecting when hooked up to RGB 16x32 LED Matrix

Tags: arduino-uno, rgb-led, mkr1000

[This tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix/connecting-with-jumper-wires) is from 2012, before the MKR1000 existed. The tutorial says the 16x32 LED Matrix panel is compatible with the Arduino Zero, which the MKR1000 is supposedly related to, so I'm thinking I should be able to upload the same program. However, the board keeps disconnecting every time I try to upload a simple sketch, so I am worried that perhaps they are not compatible. I am using the same wiring as the Arduino Uno (using pins 2-10, A0, A1, A2, GND on the MKR1000) that you can see in this tutorial

Comment: without anything wired to pins is it OK with upload?

Comment: Yes, for example I am able to upload the "Blink" program just fine.